# how jlink working when load elf and handling

Tags: embedded, stm32, elf, segger-jlink, st-link

When using "jflashlite.exe" to load an ELF file that contains multiple sections, it seems to recognize all the sections but only manages to load the internal section. Oddly, it doesn't raise any error despite skipping the external sections during the loading process. On the other hand, "stlink"(cubeProgrammer) also detects all the sections in the ELF file, but encounters a problem during loading. It explicitly states that it can't load the external sections and subsequently fails to complete the upload.

I can manage to load an external section using a different tool. However, the primary issue persists

During debugging with J-Link, it appears to handle the situation by proceeding successfully, possibly by disregarding or bypassing certain sections like the external ones. This behavior might be why the debugging process continues without a hitch. However, ST-Link takes a more stringent approach. It fails to debug due to its inability to load all sections, especially the external ones, which it explicitly flags as a problem during the upload of the ELF file.

Comment: i found some answers.
 "debugging" and "flashing" are entirely distinct operations - a click-whiz toolflow might try to do them together in sequence, but it's fully possible to fire up a debugging pointed at one .elf and point it at a target that contains what may or may not be the same executable - in which case it's up to you to make sure they match.